# Java library to render static SWF to raster image

Tags: java, android, flash, png

Do you know a Java library to render static SWF file (no animation, just raster and vector images on a canvas) to PNG? I know swfrender (a part of swftools) but I need java, not C.

Comment: Does swfrender have a large list of dependencies? It might be possible to use a JNI wrapper.

Comment: I ended up with custom java and objective-c code to render things I needed.